# I have a list which shows 1, 2, 3 numbers, can I convert them to urdu?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an ordered list in HTML which starts from 1 and goes on but it is in English digits. I want to use arabic digits. What should I do?

```
<ol>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this style:

```css
ol {list-style: arabic-indic;}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
</ol>
```

or like this:

```html
<ol style="list-style: arabic-indic;">
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: can i use list style in html without making css?

Comment: yes you can...
use <ol style="list-style: arabic-indic;">